# Co-finite sets in an infinte set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $X$ is an infinte set
And $A$$\subset$$X$ is co-finite

Can I conclude that $A$ is infinite
Because $X$$=$$A$$\cup$$(X-A)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The union of two finite sets is finite, so since $X\setminus A$ is finite and $X$ is infinite, then $A$ must be infinite.